# Where does Visual Studio look for debug symbols at all?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I know that debug symbols can be stored both in a pdb file and in the compiled binary file,

which of them does VS search for when we are debugging ?

Comment: I think you might be able to control this in options somewhere, but by default it looks for ones in pdb file.

Comment: Is there any reference links?

Comment: Not sure this answers your question, but check out http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx